# Generate sparse vector for all the column values in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, minhash

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |

Now I want to calculate the hash or sparse vector  of all the values in column1 and column2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`VectorAssembler`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.html). It creates `SparseVector` by default.

Comment: This creates a vector that concatenate the values of the two columns. The question  is related to the Vector Sparse to train an FM-like model, which uses indices of the columns